# Inequality for sum to the exponent of $q>1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, estimation, young-inequality

In this question: [How to use $\lesssim$ when using exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895202/how-to-use-lesssim-when-using-exponents) I already asked about an inequality for a sum to the exponent of $2$.

Now I wonder if $\forall q>1$, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ it holds that
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^q\leq C (1+x^q).
\end{align*}

I tried to work with an integer $k\geq q$ and exploit convexity in the positive real numbers, but that was the wrong way since it only lead me to $(1+x)^q\leq C(1+x^k)$. In some way one might use Young's inequality but I didn't manage to do it.

Comment: Applying Jensen to $x\mapsto x^q$ should give the inequality.

Comment: In fact it follows from one of your [previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994257/young-like-inequality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a short summary, thanks to @leoli:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2^{q}}(1+x)^q=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2})^q\leq\frac{1}{2}\cdot1^q+\frac{1}{2}x^q,
\end{align*}

so $C=2^{q-1}$.